# How to publish message from AWS lambda function to AWS IoT Core using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

My lambda function gets triggered by the iot core and should publish a message to another topic. I tried to do a sample in node.js and it works, but now I want to use C# for my function. My problem is that there is not really a documentation how to do this or which properties are required. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hi Niklas. Just a question - if your node.js function works why not just use it? There's not really any advantage to using C# if you already have something that does the job. In fact, we've started steering away from C# in favour of node.js when we can because the startup times for node.js are generally much faster than C#.

Comment: I just wanted to know how this can be done, because my existing project is written in C#. This existing project is running on my PC and now I want to put this functions of the project in the AWS Cloud. So there would be the advantage of not changing my working code and therefore not wasting time.

Comment: I understand. Which dev environment are you using? Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2017

Comment: You might need to have installed AWS' VS Toolkit (https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/) but you can get a shell project together by choosing File, New Project, Visual C#, AWS Lambda, AWS Lambda Project. Note that you have to use .Net Core, FW 4.7.1 is not supported. This documentation seems to have a lot of detail too: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html. Hope this helps. Regards, Adam.